# Managing and storing wildcard certificates

Tags: ssl, deployment

I've purchased a wildcard certificate. How do I keep it safe while making it generally available to all of the projects I need to deploy?

Answer (score 1):

Your private key should make your wildcard certificate safe.

As per rule, the CSR must be generated to where you want to install the certificate. You can install a certificate to different server types. Knowing that, for every server, you will need to generate a CSR. For every CSR you will have a unique private key.

This private key is also protected by the password that you initially set.

There are some CA that offers Auto-CSR wherein they will generate the CSR for you. This is more secure since the password for they private key will be the combination of the password that you set initially and the password set by the CA.

Here is an example of Auto-CSR: https://www.globalsign.com/support/csr/autocsr_domain_organization.php

Hope this helps!